# Is it possible to include content from a div defined inside a jsp page into another jsp page inside "a href", without importing the whole jsp page?

Tags: jsp, html, import

A possible solution, but with importing, would be:

firstPage.jsp

```
...
<div id="firstName"> <p> First Name </p> </div>
...
```

secondPage.jsp

```
...

<%@include file="firstName.jsp" %>
<a href="#firstName">First Name</a>
...
```

What I want to do is something like this:

secondPage.jsp

```
...
<a href="secondPage.jsp#firstName">First Name</a>
...
```

Is it possible to reference the div from the first jsp page in the second jsp page without importing the first jsp page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Iframe as the target of the link.As a result the result of the link will be shown inside the iframe which will be in the same page.